Question involving invariant mean

I'm confused about the definition of $\phi(h)=\mu(u\mapsto\phi(ue_{A}u^{*}))$ where $0\leq h\leq 1$ is positive.

Why does such an $h$ exist?
Why does it belong to $B'$?


For 1, recall that $B = (B_\ast)^\ast$, so to show the existence of $h$, it suffices to prove that $B_\ast \ni \phi \mapsto \mu(u \mapsto \phi(ue_Au^\ast))$ is a bounded linear functional on $B_\ast$, which is not hard once you work through all the definitions. Then, to show $0 \leq h \leq 1$, it suffices to check $\phi(h) = \mu(u \mapsto \phi(ue_Au^\ast)) \in [0, 1]$ for all normal states $\phi \in B_\ast$. Again, this is not hard to check once you sort through the definitions. I'll leave these for you to check. (Though I will add more details if requested.)
For 2, to show $h \in B'$, it suffices to show $vhv^\ast = h$ for all $v \in U(B)$, which is equivalent to $\phi(vhv^\ast) = \phi(h)$ for all $\phi \in B_\ast$ and $v \in U(B)$. Now, by definition, $\phi(h) = \mu(u \mapsto \phi(ue_Au^\ast))$, and it is not hard to check - as $\phi(v \cdot v^\ast)$ is an element of $B_\ast$ - that,
$$\phi(vhv^\ast) = \mu(u \mapsto \phi(vue_Au^\ast v^\ast))$$
Note that the function $u \mapsto \phi(vue_Au^\ast v^\ast)$ is a translation of the function $u \mapsto \phi(ue_Au^\ast)$, so as $\mu$ is an invariant mean, applying $\mu$ to them yields the same result, i.e., $\phi(vhv^\ast) = \phi(h)$, as required.

Is an invariant mean $\mu$ just a positive linear functional on $\ell^{\infty}(\mathcal{U}(B))$ such that $\mu(f_{v})=\mu(f)$ where $f_{v}(u)=f(v^{*}u)$?

If so, then isn't $\phi\mapsto\mu(u\mapsto\phi(ue_{A}u^{*}))$ just bounded by $|\mu|$?

@SihOASHoihd For the first question, yes. For the second question, if by “bounded by $|\mu|$” you meant the norm of the linear functional is bounded by $|\mu|$, then also yes.

And I suppose it suffices to check that $\phi(h)\in[0,1]$ for states $\phi$ because every element of $B_{*}$ is a finite linear combination of normal states?

@SihOASHoihd More or less, yes.

you start with a normal functional of norm 1 and then write it as a linear combination of normal states and argue that because it has norm 1 its value is still less than or equal to 1, right?

nevermind that doesn't work. why is it sufficient to check it for states?

@SihOASHoihd That’s not what I meant, an element is completely characterized by its evaluation at normal states because normal states span everything. Positivity is characterized by $\phi(h) \geq 0$ for all normal states $\phi$, and if you’re positive then there’s a normal state that’s nearly norm-achieving, so in particular if $h$ is positive and $h \not\leq 1$ there would be a normal state $\phi$ s.t. $\phi(h) > 1$.

oh, of course, thank you

wait, sorry, I am not seeing why there's a normal state that's nearly norm-achieving. Is this part of a more general fact?

@SihOASHoihd Just represent the algebra on a Hilbert space. Any vector state is a normal state, and vector states are clearly nearly norm-achieving.
